# How to simplify JS code with nested coroutines and promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have this **snippet of working code** that I really want to simplify. It is targeted for **Node.js v6.0** with the packages **bluebird & co**.  This is a typical situation and I would like to get to the point that the code is compact and easy to understand so I can reuse it in other projects.

The function returns one checklist with a number of item categories (1:m), and each category contains a number of items (1:m:n). So it is an **object with 2 nested levels**:

```
Root: Checklist
    Level 1: Checklist Item Group(s)
        Level 2: Checklist Item(s)
```

The root level (1 checklist) and one level down (checklist item categories) can be implemented in the generator function by yielding.

The 1:n:m level cannot use "yield" when I would use e.g. Promise.mapSeries() over checklist.__node__ChecklistItemGroups because a "yield" is only supported in the main generator function, not in the map inner function. So I reverted back to the function Promise.each() and a Promise.then() construct.

```
function getGraphChecklistById(pId) {
    return co(function *() {
        let checklist = yield getChecklistById(pId); // Returns a promise.
        checklist.__node__ChecklistItemGroups = yield fetchChecklistItemGroupsByChecklistId(pId); // Returns a promise.
        return checklist;
    })
        .then(function (checklist) {
            return Promise.each(
                checklist.__node__ChecklistItemGroups,
                function (pItem) {
                    return fetchChecklistItemsByXrefId(pItem.xchlclig_id).then(function (result) {  // fetchChecklistItemsByXrefId() returns a promise.
                        pItem.__node__ChecklistItems = result;
                    });
                })
                .then(function (unused) {
                    return checklist;
                });
        })
}
```

This is an example result:

```
result: {
    "checklist-field-1": 1,
    "checklist-field-2": 1,
    "__node__ChecklistItemGroups": [
        {
            "checklist-group-field-1": 1,
            "checklist-group-field-2": 1,
            "__node__ChecklistItems": [
                {
                    "checklist-item-field-1": 1,
                    "checklist-item-field-2": 1,
                },
                {
                    "checklist-item-field-1": 2,
                    "checklist-item-field-2": 2,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "checklist-group-field-1": 2,
            "checklist-group-field-2": 2,
            "__node__ChecklistItems": [
                {
                    "checklist-item-field-1": 1,
                    "checklist-item-field-2": 1,
                },
                {
                    "checklist-item-field-1": 2,
                    "checklist-item-field-2": 2,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions from a Promise/Coroutines expert? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write it like this - without `Promise.each` but a plain loop:

```
let getGraphChecklistById = Promise.coroutine(function*(pId) {
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Don't put co(…) in a function, wrap directly
    let checklist = yield getChecklistById(pId);
    checklist.__node__ChecklistItemGroups = yield fetchChecklistItemGroupsByChecklistId(pId); // Returns a promise.
    for (let pItem of checklist.__node__ChecklistItemGroups) {
//  ^^^ iteration in series like Promise.each does it
        let result = yield fetchChecklistItemsByXrefId(pItem.xchlclig_id);
//                   ^^^^^ You can use yield here as it's not an extra function
        pItem.__node__ChecklistItems = result;
    }
    return checklist;
});
```

Whether you use Bluebird's `Promise.coroutine` or `co.wrap` doesn't really matter here.

And if you want to iterate the groups in parallel, you still can use `yield` in the callback function if you make that a generator:

```
let getGraphChecklistById = Promise.coroutine(function*(pId) {
    let checklist = yield getChecklistById(pId); 
    checklist.__node__ChecklistItemGroups = yield fetchChecklistItemGroupsByChecklistId(pId); // Returns a promise.
    yield Promise.map(
        checklist.__node__ChecklistItemGroups,
        Promise.coroutine(function*(pItem) {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ pass this as the promise-returning callback function
            let result = yield fetchChecklistItemsByXrefId(pItem.xchlclig_id);
            pItem.__node__ChecklistItems = result;
        })
    );
    return checklist;
});
```

Comment: Thanks bergi for shaving off 50% of the #lines of code:) The clue is indeed that a for-of iteration does not need an inner function.

Comment: I have applied the recommended changes and kept using the co package. Final result https://gist.github.com/pantaluna/312627ee61742850eb679c7d5125e20d

Comment: @Rolf: I still think you're better off using `co.wrap` (and can save two more lines).

Comment: Okay done that. https://gist.github.com/pantaluna/6a3cb8e0a96575bf3302931528e022a4 I also removed the dependency on 'co'.

I find it difficult to grasp that I can pass a parameter and that it gets passed to the generator function (pId). let getGraphChecklistById = Promise.coroutine(function*(pId) {